# Try to concatenate tensors of inconsistent batch size in tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow2.x

I trie to concatenate 2 tensors of different batch size within a function decorated with @tf.function. I tried 2 methods and the first one is listed as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function  # indispensable
def fun1(tensors, indices):
    results = []

    for i in tf.range(2):  # batch size = 2
        pos = tf.where(indices==i)
        emb = tf.gather_nd(tensors, pos)
        # do something to emb, but do nothing here for simplicity.
        results += [emb]

    results = tf.concat(results, axis=0)
    return results

tensors = tf.random.uniform((5, 2))
fun1(tensors, indices=[0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

But it raises errors as following:

```
TypeError: 'results' does not have the same nested structure after one iteration.
The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
First structure: type=list str=[]
Second structure: type=list str=[<tf.Tensor 'while/GatherNd:0' shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32>]

More specifically: The two structures don't have the same number of elements. First structure: type=list str=[]. Second structure: type=list str=[<tf.Tensor 'while/GatherNd:0' shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32>]
Entire first structure:
[]
Entire second structure:
[.]
```

So I tried the second method:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function  # indispensable
def fun2(tensors, indices):
    results = tf.reshape(tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32), (0, 2))  # make empty tensors

    for i in tf.range(2):  # batch size = 2
        pos = tf.where(indices==i)
        emb = tf.gather_nd(tensors, pos)
        # do something to emb, but do nothing here for simplicity
        results = tf.concat([results, emb], axis=0)

    return results

tensors = tf.random.uniform((5, 2))
fun2(tensors, indices=[0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

But it raises errors:

```
ValueError: 'results' has shape (0, 2) before the loop, but shape (None, 2) after one iteration. Use tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options to set shape invariants.
```

How should I resolve the problems? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found I could achieve it by adding one line of codes to the second method as following:

```
@tf.function
def fun2(tensors, indices):
    results = tf.reshape(tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32), (0, 2))  # make empty tensors

    for i in tf.range(2):  # batch size = 2
        tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(shape_invariants=[(results, tf.TensorShape([None, 2]))])

        pos = tf.where(indices==i)
        emb = tf.gather_nd(tensors, pos)
        # do something to emb, but do nothing here for simplicity
        results = tf.concat([results, emb], axis=0)

    return results
```